# If record has user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Users have many cards and cards have many users, with a has_many through relationship.

```
# card.rb
has_many :card_assignments
has_many :users, :through => :card_assignments

# user.rb
has_many :card_assignments
has_many :cards, :through => :card_assignments

# card_assignment.rb
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :card
```

In my view, I want to check if the current user is one of the users which belongs to the card, if that makes sense?

Comment: You could use [`exists?`](http://devdocs.io/rails~5.0/activerecord/findermethods#method-i-exists-3F), e.g. `@card.card_assigments.exists?(user_id: current_user.id)` or `current_user.card_assignments.exists?(card_id: @card.id)`. This would perform a database query each time it's used, so depending on how many cards you'd like to check, `current_user.card_assignment_ids.include?(@card.id)` might also help (this should at least automatically cache the database query results).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
if @card.user_ids.include?(current_user.id)
```